# Passing scope_identity parameter from DAL to UI layer

Tags: c#, winforms

I'm retrieveing the last id inserted on sql server with scope_identity. I'm working with 3 layers. How can I pass the id value from DAL layer to UI layer. Thanks in advance.

Comment: Via a Stored Procedure. One method people commonalty use is echo the object that was inserted or updated (select the same object in the insert/update sp call). During an insert this would return the identity.

Comment: I'm already have the last id value, I need pass that value from DAL layer to UI layer @Ross Bush

Comment: What are you currently passing to the UI?

Comment: I have a form in UI where I put about 300 entries. I need save my progress when I put 50 or 100 entries. All the process is done with stored procedures. I succesfully retrieve the ID in DAL layer. I need to get the ID in the UI layer to edit the current entries. Sorry for my english, is not my primary language @Ross Bush